# Liberar acesso externo no sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, amazon-aws

tenho uma máquina na amazon, e está instalado o sql server porém não consigo acessar de fora do servidor. Gostaria de saber se há alguma configuração além de liberar o protocolo no Security group.

Answer (score 3):

O erro mais comum é montar a string de conexão errada.

Você por acaso está adicionando a porta do ENDPOINT na string de conexão?

Você precisa copiar o nome do ENDPOINT (algo como sqlsvr-pdz.c6c8mdfntzgv0.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com) e depois colocar uma ',' e a porta de conexão do ENDPOINT, no final a string deve ficar algo parecido com isto:

```
sqlsvr-pdz.c6c8mdfntzgv0.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433
```

O ENDPOINT e a porta de conexão você consegue na tela do Management Consoles, na descrição do servidor, você tem essas duas informações.

Lembrando também que o usuário e senha a ser usado no MSSQL Management Studio é o usuário e senha do master user do SQL, não sua conta AWS.